# Salesforce and third party SQL database

Tags: rest-api

I have a website where client data is saved in an sql database.

When a client is created on my website, I need to also create that same client inside Salesforce.

Likewise, when a client is created within Salesforce. I need to push that new client to my database to be saved.

Is there a way inside salesforce to know when a new object is created so I can push that data to my backend?

How can I go about this?

Comment: Take a look [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration), it goes over the options

Comment: @identigral Thanks, I took a look and I'm a tad still confused. It seems like Apex would be useful but from what I know Apex only triggers after or before events. Bit confused which one to use for my use case.